# JavaScript instead of "echo"

Tags: javascript, php, echo

So this is part of my table. But the part where I use "echo" is (according to my boss) not a good solution. 
I have to do it somehow with JavaScript. 
I don't really understand what is wrong with "echo", can please somebody explain? 
and how do I use JS instead of "echo"?

```
<td>Projekt: </td>
    <td><select name="Projekt">
         <?php 
         $result = mysql_query("select name from project");   
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
             echo '<option value="" selected> </option>';
             echo '<option value="' .$row['name'] .'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
          }
         ?>
         </select>       
  </td>
```

Comment: Ask your boss what is wrong with it. Depends on the implementation. There is nothing wrong with `echo`.

Comment: You can use document.write() method

Comment: If you don't want use echo use ajax of jquery.

Comment: There is something you are not telling us - why have Javascript involved in this at all?

Comment: @putvande I think he means that it's not ideal. And he wants me to learn JS.

Comment: Either your boss is a moron, or something is missing, as the code in the question is exactly how you should do that, not counting the deprecated and unsecure `mysql_*` methods.

Comment: Please change your name and your user's profile description. It's not a place to use offensive language (and those words are clearly curses in polish).

Comment: @kamituel it's my familly name, and you are beeing offensive.

Comment: @JebajłoRypacz - yeah, and your first name is "Jebajło". There's no such name. You might fool most people here, but I do speak polish.

Comment: If your boss is meant to be mentoring you, ask him to go through his alternative with you; simply telling someone that their implementation is incorrect without explaining its shortcomings and potential improvements is unhelpful at best.

Comment: @kamituel it's obvious that you speak polish, but as ignorat as you are, it is still offensive for me. please don't do it anymore, or I will report you.

Comment: @JebajłoRypacz - I've already reported you. You can report me as well, be my guest - just remember to point out how I abuse rules of SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice a few basic design flaws in your code that might be related to what your boss has asked you to do.

You really shouldn't have database query code in your template php file, mixed with your html code. To avoid that, you should use a [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) or similar approach in case you want to render your templates server-side. There are frameworks and libraries like [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) or [Symfony](http://symfony.com/) that can help you achieve this by doing most of the work for you.

Anyway, in order to render those options with Javascript, you'd need first solve the problem of getting them to your user's browser (as other users have commented already). You could easily make an AJAX call with [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (plenty of docs and tutorials on this if you google it) but assuming that you already have them stored in a Javascript variable, you could write something like this (it uses jQuery):

```
<td>Projekt: </td>
<td>
  <select name="Projekt" id="projects">
    <option value="" selected> </option>
  </select>       
</td>

<script>
  // projects are stored in a variable named projects
  var select = $('#projects');
  projects.forEach(function(project) {
    select.append('<option value="'+project+'">'+project+'</option>');
  });
</script>
```

There are plenty of Javascript frameworks and libraries too that will help you to achieve this kind of behavior letting you use templating, data binding and other useful stuff like in [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/), [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/), etc.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

This is PHP and there's nothing wrong with this code apart from echoing out HTML tags which maybe what he means. Try this:

```
<td>Projekt: </td>
  <td><select name="Projekt">
       <option value="" selected="">
       <?php 
       $result = mysql_query("select name from project");   
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>"><?php echo $row['name'] ?></option>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
       </select>       
</td>
```

Also notice how I've moved `<option value="" selected="">`. If it's in the `while` loop you'll get lots of them which I suspect is not what you want :)

Comment: Maybe it is what his boss means but it is for sure not easier to read/understand - It should all be kept in PHP to have the same look-and-feel

Comment: No, ideally you should have the two together at *all* but this solution is better than the original code because it's then you can write and manipulate the HTML without worrying about escaping which soon becomes a huge mess. I would usually use `<?= ?>` which makes it a *lot* more readable but I'm unsure on OP's server settings / knowledge of said tags.